# Model Binding MVC3 Razor, How do I change input name?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-binding

I have setup a basic model binder by passing in a list to a view and running:

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult AddTracks(int id)
{
    TrackRepository trackRepository = new TrackRepository();
    //ShowTrackAssociationHelper showTrack = new ShowTrackAssociationHelper();

    //showTrack.tracks = trackRepository.GetAssociatedTracks(id).ToList();
    //showTrack.show = showRepository.GetShow(id);
    TracksViewModel tracksModel = new TracksViewModel();
    tracksModel.Tracks = trackRepository.GetAssociatedTracks(id);

    ViewBag.ShowID = id;
    return View(tracksModel);


}
```

View:

```
 @model BluesNetwork.Models.TracksViewModel
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tracks, "TrackEditor")
```

TracksView Model:

```
public class TracksViewModel
{

    public IEnumerable<Track> Tracks  { get; set; }

}
```

TackEditor:

```
 @model BluesNetwork.Models.Track
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TrackID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ShowID)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TrackNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TrackNumber, new { maxlength = 2 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TrackNumber)
        </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HQFileID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LQFileID)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InternalRating)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InternalRating)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InternalRating)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.License)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.License)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.License)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LicenseNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LicenseNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LicenseNumber)
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" />





}
```

At first I was getting:

Which gives me output as such on each input:

name="[0].ShowID"

however I wanted it to be:

name="track[0].ShowID"

I've seen examples/tutorials that show output like this but they don't go into detail about it.

After following RPM1984's advice and making the changes I got the error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[BluesNetwork.Models.Track]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'BluesNetwork.Models.Track'.

Thank you in advance for all help

At

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "I have setup a basic model binder". That doesn't look like a model binder, that looks like a template or partial view.

Anyway, moving on....

You should have a ViewModel like this:

```
public class TracksViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
}
```

**Main View:**

```
@model TracksViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tracks)
```

**Editor Template:**

```
@model Track
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ShowId)
```

No loops, no magic strings. Nice.

Which will render HTML like this:

```
<input type="text" name="tracks[0].ShowId" />
<input type="text" name="tracks[1].ShowId" />
<input type="text" name="tracks[2].ShowId" />
```

Which is what you want, right?

Comment: Thats what I want, but when I try your solution I get:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[BluesNetwork.Models.Track]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'BluesNetwork.Models.Track'.

Comment: @dreadlocks1221 - show the code for your controller action method which returns this view. Looks like your returning the EF query, when you should be materializing the query first, e.g `var model = new TracksViewModel { Tracks = db.Tracks.ToList() }; return View(model);`. You should probably also use a ViewModel for `Track` as well, but one step at a time.

Comment: @dreadlocks1221 - yep, i'm guessing `trackRepository.GetAssociatedTracks(id)` returns either `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`. You need to fire the query in your controller, like i said above.

Comment: So then why doesn't the track view model require list instead of Ienumerable?

Comment: @dreadlocks1221 - `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Did you just try what i said?

Comment: I modified it to be tracksModel.Tracks = trackRepository.GetAssociatedTracks(id).ToList(); and I get the error:The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BluesNetwork.Models.Track]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'BluesNetwork.Models.Track'. The error seems to be on the editor template

Comment: @dreadlocks1221 - it's because of this line: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tracks, "TrackEditor")`. Get rid of the "TrackEditor" parameter, and name your editor template `Track.cshtml`. When you specify the template name, MVC will expect the template to be bound to a list. But by leaving it out, MVC will first use the built-in template to render the list for you template x number of times.

Comment: Did that, and now my editors aren't showing up, I have a template in Shared/EditorTemplates/Tracks.cshtml

Comment: i give up mate. i've given you all the info/help i can, but your missing something that i've said in the above comments or in my answer.

Comment: Do you have or know where I can download a working example (that would probably help)?

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you want to change the names you will need to bust out some JavaScript or roll your own partial view.

Note that changing id's and names of bound fields is, generally speaking, a poor idea because this will break the baked in binding of your ViewModel. Do you really need to change the name?